# Selenium with Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, selenium

Trying to utilize 'def assert_alert_present(): function to automate assertion when alert is present. Would like to use it on 'sign up' button for Walmart.com where it comes by default like this:

Your password must contain between 6 and 12 characters, with no spaces. Please try again.

I deliberately use less then 6 or more than 12 characters and alert comes up. Not sure how to write function for that alert so it pass if the alert is there and fails if the alert is not present.

Comment: share your code, what you have tried

Comment: driver.find_element_by_name("firstName").send_keys("Vasa")
driver.find_element_by_name("lastName").send_keys("Pupkin")
driver.find_element_by_name("email").send_keys("VasaPupkin@gmail.com")
driver.find_element_by_name("password").send_keys("VasaPupkin1234")
driver.find_element_by_id("signup-submit-btn").click()

#def assert_alert_present():

Comment: at this time I am @ https://www.walmart.com/account/signup page

Comment: The goal of this test is to assert that alert message is present: "Your password must contain between 6 and 12 characters, with no spaces. Please try again."  Not sure exactly of a syntax and steps  how to use : 'def assert_alert_present(): function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hope this is what you are looking for:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By


def assert_alert_present():
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    driver.maximize_window()
    baseurl = "https://www.walmart.com/account/signup"
    driver.get(baseurl)

    driver.find_element_by_name("firstName").send_keys("Vasa")
    driver.find_element_by_name("lastName").send_keys("Pupkin")
    driver.find_element_by_name("email").send_keys("abc@123.com")
    driver.find_element_by_name("password").send_keys("123")

    #this will check and verify the alertpopup
    try:
        assert driver.find_element(By.ID, "password-help")
        print "Alert is present"
    except:
        print "Alert is not present"

    driver.find_element_by_css_selector("button.l-margin-top").click()

    errormessage = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.error-label').text

    if errormessage.strip() == "Your password must contain between 6 and 12 characters, with no spaces. Please try again.":
        print "Error lable is present there "
    else:
        print "Error lable is not present on website, Please check the website "

assert_alert_present()
```

this will print the message:

```
Alert is present
Error lable is present there
```

Comment: Thank You. It Runs perfect.  Just something to clarify. I have hard time to find that alert element by id. "assert driver.find_element(By.ID, "password-help")". When I click on that gray alert it just disappears. The only reference to it i found when looked at the same red error message under the "Password" field after entering "123" password. It was on a top of it in a DOM.

Comment: Happy Thanksgiving!

Comment: Happy Thanksgiving.  div class="validation-group" data-reactid=".0.0.1.0.1.3.4.1.0.1"><span id="password-help" class="visuallyhidden" data-reactid=".0.0.1.0.1.3.4.1.0.1.1">Your password must be between 6 and 12 characters.</span> this is the html of that popup